# Can I extend my guitar's jack socket without a lead?

Tags: electric-guitar

I have an electric guitar whose jack socket is recessed in the body of the guitar, [image: as shown in this image]

I have received a birthday present of a wireless jack connector, but the "transmitter" part is too fat to fit inside the recessed mini-tunnel that houses the jack socket.

I could buy a pair of mini-full jack lead converters to extend the lead, but...

Is there a neater way, e.g. a single jack extender without a cable part?

Comment: Is your guitar output jack at an angle from the front of the guitar similar to a strat or recessed into the edge of the guitar similar to a telecaster?

Comment: I've uploaded a picture just to explain a bit better hopefully

Comment: I've looked in one of my Stewart MacDonald catalogs and they show a Les Paul jack plate that would fit over that hole very nicely. Allparts probably has something that would work too. Look under hardware.

Answer (score 2):

You could make up a custom cable using George L's and a socket connector like the one on [this cable](https://www.amazon.co.uk/kenable-Premium-6-35mm-Extension-Stereo/dp/B00B2J4U72). Knowing how to build cables is useful for guitar pedals as well.

See [George L's - Connecting with your tone](https://online.berklee.edu/takenote/george-ls-connecting-with-your-tone/)

Comment: Yes, that sounds good - it's just that I'm a total amateur and don't have the tools to do this - i was looking for an off-the-shelf.  I went into the big guitar shop in our town and the sales person was not terribly interested in helping me out :-(

Comment: It requires very little knowledge or experience to do this. Well worth a shot. An alternative that involves no electrical experience is to actually widen the hole the socket sits in. Quick and simple, but rather permanent.

Answer (score 2):

If the jack is located on the edge of the guitar, you might consider replacing the recessed cup with a flat plate and mounting the jack into the plate instead of the recessed cup. I've seen them both ways so I know they exist.